# How do you delete Child from Parent entities in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.0

I have these class

```
public class HomeSection2
{
    public HomeSection2()
    {
        HomeSection2Detail = new List<HomeSection2Detail>();
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public virtual List<HomeSection2Detail> HomeSection2Detail { get; set; }
}

public class HomeSection2Detail
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public int? Sequence { get; set; }

    public virtual HomeSection2 HomeSection2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I call

```
var obj2detail = obj2.HomeSection2Detail.Where(w => w.ID == detail.ID).FirstOrDefault();
if (obj2detail != null)
{
    obj2.HomeSection2Detail.Remove(obj2detail);
}
```

From my Application, it will only remove the relationship but not the record in the Database.

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `obj2`?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin: `HomeSection2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following. Explainations added as comments in the snippet:

```
var obj2detail = obj2.HomeSection2Detail.Where(w => w.ID == detail.ID).FirstOrDefault();
if (obj2detail != null)
{
    // this line of code only delete the relationship.
    obj2.HomeSection2Detail.Remove(obj2detail);

    // If you want to delete the entity you need the DbContext help 
    // and your HomeSection2Details DbSet<HomeSection2Detail> like below
    yourDbContext.HomeSection2Details.Remove(obj2detail);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the entity explicitly from `HomeSection2Details` DbSet.

```
dbContext.HomeSection2Details.Remove(obj2detail);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to explicitly remove the dependent entity from the `DbContext`; if a dependent entity should *always* be deleted when removed from it's principal entity, this can be achieved through configuration on the `DbContext`, using `OnDelete`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .Entity<HomeSection2>()
        .HasMany(x => x.HomeSection2Detail)
        .WithOne(x => x.HomeSection2)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Causes dependent entity to be deleted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you use direct from RemoveRange or Remove DbContext

```
 _db.RemoveRange(obj2detail);
```